# Audit functionality for rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement an audit functionality for some of my rails models and store it on an external "event" database (we chose BigQuery).

Each event should be very basic:
before_json, after_json, diff, action, object_id

So, I started building this concern that I am planning on adding to my models:

```
module Auditable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    before_destroy {audit(:destroy)}

    after_validation on: :update do
      audit(:update)
    end

    after_validation on: :create do
      audit(:create)
    end

    def audit(action)
      EventSender.send(before_json, self.to_json, diff, action, self.id)
    end
  end
end
```

The only thing I dont know how to implement is getting the before state of the object so I can populate the relevant fields and the diff between the two states.

Any ideas on how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

```
module Auditable
  require 'active_record/diff'

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include ActiveRecord::Diff

    before_destroy {audit(:destroy, before: before_state)}

    after_validation on: :update do
      audit(:update, before: before_state, after: self)
    end

    after_create do
      audit(:create, after: self)
    end

    def audit(action, before: {}, after: {})
      diff = case action
             when :update
               before.diff(after)
             when :create
               after
             when :destroy
               before
             end

      BigQueryClient.new.insert(
        self.class.to_s.downcase,
        {
          before: before.to_json,
          after: after.to_json,
          diff: diff.to_json,
          action: action,
          "#{self.class.to_s.downcase.to_sym}_id": self.id
        },
        dataset_name: "audit"
      )
    end

    private

    def before_state
      self.class.find(self.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that I'm using an external gem called "activerecord-diff" to calculate the diff between the before and after.